# Is it possible to select * where then add all results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql table with a `user_id` and an `integer`

Is it possible to select `integer` from table where `user_id` = ?
then add all integer results together and return just the one integer result?

Comment: Yes, this is called a `SUM()`.

Comment: To amplify:  "select user_id, sum(integer_value) from my_table group by user_id;"

Comment: @TGray You dont need `group by` OP use `where user_id =? `

Comment: `select sum(thatInt) as theSum from myTable where userId=x`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Thanks.  My query was predicated on not-having-read-the-whole-statement.  My comment was more along the lines of "teach" vs "go look it up."

Comment: Dupe close: In your case it would be for a single user. Same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
SELECT sum(integer) As ReturnValue
FROM table
WHERE user_id = [value]
```

Answer (score 2):

yes - try something along of the lines of:

```
SELECT SUM(integer) FROM tbl WHERE user_id = 'xxx'
```